# Accessing an element in index.html in Angular 7 from other components

Tags: angular

I need to show a chat widget only if the use is logged. The script that shows this chat will be executed in index.html. But I need to validate if the user is logged to show this widget.

And I don`t kown where I have to place this code. The widget starts hidden by css in index.html and I need to show if the user is logged.
The code to show the widget is:

```
// Show the widget.
document.getElementById("md-app-widget").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>APP</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <style type="text/css">
            // Start widget hidden.
            .md-chat-widget-wrapper {
              visibility: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <hb-app>
            <div class="sk-fading-circle">
                <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
            </div>
        </hb-app>
        <!-- This script shows a chat widget that be visible only with user is logged -->
        <script type="text/javascript">var mdChatClient="8AE83B4E23CE3A1671875001A27";</script>
        <script src="https://chat.movidesk.com/Scripts/chat-widget.min.js"></script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason that you need to place the chat widget in the root component?

Comment: I didn`t know how to put in other componente. But I resolved, inserting the script in home.component by appendChild.

Answer (score 0):

use can simply use this:

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('username') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved, adding the script in home.component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.executaScriptMovidesk();
    }

    private executaScriptMovidesk() {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://chat.movidesk.com/Scripts/chat-widget.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

And in the login.component, I made the chat hidden:

```
ngOnInit() {
   let movideskChat = document.getElementById("md-app-widget");
        if (movideskChat)
            movideskChat.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```